Conditions for the existence of stationary state distribution
If the Markov chain induced by the policy is ergodic, then the state distribution under the policy is stationary.
Are there some conditions/properties (sufficient or necessary, on the MDP or on the policy) to check if a policy induces an ergodic Markov chain? (Beside stationary transition and stationary policy).
